# Any way to change the function of keyboard button particularly right ctrl

Tags: keyboard

I want to change the functionality of my right ctrl to work as right click of the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoHotkey to remap as follows: `RControl::RButton` (can use *RCtrl* too).